# Erro ao usar whereRaw no Laravel

Tags: php, querybuilder

O que estou fazendo de errado nesta *queryRaw*? O objetivo é exibir os valores somados **se** ID = ID, mas estou obtendo a soma total da coluna.

**Trecho da *query feita no *Controller*:**

```
//Show
public function show( Pesquisa $pesquisa )
{
    $this->guardaAvaliacao( $pesquisa );

    $pesquisa->load( [
        'respostas' => function ( $relation ) {
            $relation->with( [ 'pergunta.opcoes', 'opcao' ] );
        }
    ] );

    $nota = DB::table('clima.tbl_resposta_super')
        ->selectRaw('sum(nota_original) as nota_original ')
        ->whereRaw('tbl_resposta_super.pesquisa_id', '=' .$pesquisa->id)
        ->groupBy('nota_original')
        ->get();


    dd($nota);

}
```

Comment: Teste colocando uma aspa simples na url ou no input se for o caso da busca). Utilize digamos, 100% do jeito Laravel. Utilize assim ->whereRaw('tbl_resposta_super.pesquisa_id = ?' , [$pesquisa->id])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao usar o `whereRaw` não precisa separar o operador como argumento, como se fosse o `where`.

```
$nota = DB::table('clima.tbl_resposta_super')
        ->selectRaw('sum(nota_original) as nota_original ')
        ->whereRaw('tbl_resposta_super.pesquisa_id = ' .$pesquisa->id)
        ->groupBy('nota_original')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Bom dia! Obrigado pela dica, resolvi o problema da seguinte forma,         //Recupera e soma Notas
        $notas = DB::table('clima.tbl_resposta_super')
            ->select(DB::raw('sum(nota_original) as nota_original,sum(nota_supervisor) as nota_supervisor, pesquisa_id'))
            ->where('tbl_resposta_super.pesquisa_id', '=', $pesquisa->id)
            ->groupBy('pesquisa_id')
            ->get();

Answer (score 0):

Para os próximos que tiverem a mesma duvida segue resolução.

```
        //Recupera e soma Notas
    $notas = DB::table('clima.tbl_resposta_super')
        ->select(DB::raw('sum(nota_original) as nota_original,sum(nota_supervisor) as nota_supervisor, pesquisa_id'))
        ->where('tbl_resposta_super.pesquisa_id', '=', $pesquisa->id)
        ->groupBy('pesquisa_id')
        ->get();
```